# How to give varray result for unit test case in sql developer

Tags: plsql

created a stored procedure with varray as out parameter as follows and created unit test case in sql developer.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EtsM.png]

when i am trying to run the unit test case, getting error like as follows.

```
Expected: [VARCHAR2()], Received: [VARCHAR2(shobha, sudha, sonnali, Rashmi, Anusha, Kiran, venkatesh, naveen, satya, venkata ramana)]
```

How can i able to give result field in unit test case.
How to validate the unit test case result by using process validation in sql developer.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to double-click on the Result value (where it Reads VARCHAR2())

Then a new edit window will open, if you right-click on the First entry you can select "Add new value" and a new value will appear below it, which you can change to "shobha" then again add new value -> "sudha" and so forth...

But be warned - this will only work as long as you don't have complex Return types like objects with nested tables and nested objects. If you are there you have to use a little work around. It is a little more typing, but the framework is still usable ;-)

[image]

Comment: I made as you suggested but problem with my example still occurs "Expected: [VARCHAR2(TEST_1, TEST_2, TEST_3)], Received: [VARCHAR2(???, ???, ???)]". How can I put my varchar2 array to execute the test properly?

Comment: Then you most likely have made a typing error, or a mistake in the order of elements in the array. I just ran a complete test-case with an array like you described and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Have you also ticked the box "Test Result" beneath only the OUT-Parameter you want to check?

Comment: Yes, I've checked only that "Test Result". Also can't see any typing error. When I run this procedure like below:  `set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
my_array strarray := strarray();
BEGIN
my_proc(3,my_array);

for i in my_array.first..my_array.last loop
dbms_output.put_line('next = ' || my_array(i));
end loop;
END;`
  I recieve:  TEST_1
TEST_2
TEST_3

Comment: I've found the cause... When I run this test on SQL Developer Version 3.0.04 - everything is fine, on the newest Version 4.0.1.14 I receive still the error. Some day, I will check the details but today - question is answered ;) What is your version?

Comment: 4.0.3.16 - seems they fixed the bug ?